# JS : Return result from nested ajax success function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

**How do I return the result of the nested ajax call as the result of the parent function?**

```
//Declaring the function
var myFunction = function(myData){  
  $.ajax({
  type:'post',
  url:"/ajaxPage.php",
  data:{data:myData},
  success:function(r){
  return r;
  });
}

//Calling the function
var theResult = myFunction(myData);
```

**I want the variable 'theResult' to hold the contents of the ajax call.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to make your AJAX call synchronous (not asynchronous which is the default).

Something like this:

```
//Declaring the function
var myFunction = function(myData){
  var returnValue = null;
  $.ajax({
  type:'post',
  async: false,
  url:"/ajaxPage.php",
  data:{data:myData},
  success:function(r){
  returnValue = r;
  });

  return returnValue;
}

//Calling the function
var theResult = myFunction(myData);
```

Comment: He didn't say that it has to be :)

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you Hancicicicici! Very interesting I didn't know you could remove the async nature of this function. Are there any other jquery functions that this can be applied to?

Comment: Making AJAX synchronous is backwards. The appropriate approach is to turn the code that handles the response into a continuation passed to myFunction`, as José's answer shows.

Answer (score 7):

Since the ajax is asynchronous you cannot return it in the parent function.
What you can do, is to provide a callback function, and you call it as well with the result.

```
 //Declaring the function

var myFunction = function(myData, callback){  
  $.ajax({
  type:'post',
  url:"/ajaxPage.php",
  data:{data:myData},
  success:function(r){
    callback(r);
  });
}


//Calling the function
var theResult = myFunction(myData, function(res) {
    // deal with it..
});
```

Comment: As the title implies - we want to return it, not to "deal with it". Like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35508182/js-return-from-nested-function-after-ajax-call

Answer (score 3):

If you're using jQuery, you should definitely be using [`$.Deferred()`](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) and [`Promises/A`](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Promises/A). I've made this more verbose that you really need  to demonstrate some of the functionality. `$.ajax` itself is already returning a `$.Deferred().promise()` so you can actually just cut out the extra step if you only need to make the one XHR request (see bottom example).

```
//Declaring the function
var myFunction = function(myData){
  var deferredResponse = new $.Deferred();
  $.ajax({
    type:  'post',
    url:   '/ajaxPage.php',
    data: {'data': myData}
  }).done(deferredResponse.resolve).fail(deferredResponse.reject);
  return deferredResponse.promise();
}

//Calling the function
$.when(myFunction(myData)).done(function(response){
  var theResult = response;
});
```

The verbose syntax comes in handy when you have multiple nested XHR requests and want to return the response of the inner-most call: `deferredResponse.resolve(innerResponse)`. Here's the simply version.

```
//Declaring the function
var myFunction = function(myData){
  return $.ajax({
    type:  'post',
    url:   '/ajaxPage.php',
    data: {'data': myData}
  });
}

//Calling the function
myFunction(myData).done(function(response){
  var theResult = response;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var myFunction = function(myData){  
  $.ajax({
  type:'post',
  url:"/ajaxPage.php",
  data:{data:myData},
  success:function(r){
       return arguments.callee(r);
  });
}

//Calling the function
var theResult = myFunction(myData);
```

Comment: Ah what does the arguments.callee() function do?

Comment: It'll call the function, self which it is in.