# return from nested function after AJAX call

Tags: javascript, ajax, function, nested, return

I have this situation where I have to check something via AJAX and then return the result.
Or simplified:

```
function isValid() {
    $.ajax(URL, data, function(response) {
        isValid = response;
    });
    return isValid;
}
```

but still can't make it.

I can access the reponse, but I can't make isValid return AFTER I get the reponse.
For example the solution I meet everywhere:

```
function isValid() {
    function checkOnServer(callback) {
        $.ajax(URL, data, function(response) {
            callback(response);
        });
    }
    checkOnServer(function(response) {
        alert(response);
    });
}
```

I met this all over Stackoverflow, BUT the problem is:

1. I don't want to alert this.
2. I want to RETURN it from isValid().

===========================

EDIT: I forgot to mention that if you/me/we try to simply "return" from the "checkOnServer" - it will just return it to the success callback of the AJAX. But the goal here is to make "isValid" return the result ... :)

Comment: You can not return from an asynchronous method. You are trying to eat the delivery pizza before it is delivered to your house. You need to use callbacks or promises. You need to change your logic.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0):

your code is sensible ,but you use your callback function in isValid() so its doesn't alert !,also I've a little bit change your ajax function below

```
function isValid() { 
  checkOnServer(function(response) {
    alert(response);
  });
}
function checkOnServer(callback) {
    $.ajax({
         url : URL,
         data : data,
         success : function(response) {
           callback(response);
         }
     });
}
```

Edit

Variable is can't return from asynchronous method ?If we call function with ajax ,call function is run first immediately before ajax is response,so it will return undefined only with above method.

`There is two method I've know to return from asynchronous function`

**Call after ajax function is done**

```
 function isValid() {
  var data; 
  checkOnServer(function(response) {
    data = response;
  });
  return data;
}
function checkOnServer(callback) {
    $.ajax({
         url : URL,
         data : data,
         async : false             
     }).done(function(response){
        callback(response);
        });
}
console.log(isValid());
```

**Assign variable with `responseText`**

```
 function isValid() { 
 var data = checkOnServer();
 return data;
}
function checkOnServer() {
    var data = $.ajax({
                 url : URL,
                 data : data,
                 async : false //must set async to false
              });
    return data.responseText;
}
console.log(isValid());
```

Comment: And in your commend - how can you make isValid() return the response ?

Comment: callback is can't return variable ,so we make all code within that call back function.What would you like to do with that return response? ,do it that in isValid()

Comment: The "isValid" is legacy, and I must use it. The only thing I can do is just adding stuff there and modify the "return" statement. (But it should always return "true" or "false" in order to perform validation.)